# Issues with 'container' element on a horizontally draggable image gallery

Tags: jquery-ui, responsive-design, flexbox, draggable, image-gallery

I'm trying to make an image gallery that's navigated by dragging horizontally. The issue I'm currently facing is that there are no boundaries on the left and right for when the elements should stop dragging. I've tried using the 'container' element, but when I do, it stops dragging altogether.

I've tried using 'parent' or the actual div as the container and neither has worked properly. I saw on another message board that using flexbox in this situation makes things more complicated, so I switched to using display: inline-block on images.

This is my current draft: https://jsfiddle.net/samseurynck/ka1e9soj/21/

HTML

```
<div class="item_block_left">
  <div class="item_block_left_gallery_container">
    <div class="item_block_left_gallery">
        <img class="item_block_left_gallery_item" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals">
        <img class="item_block_left_gallery_item" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals">
        <img class="item_block_left_gallery_item" src="https://placeimg.com/640/400/animals">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.item_block_left{
  height:200px; 
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  .item_block_left_gallery_container{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    .item_block_left_gallery{
      height:100%;
      display: flex;
      cursor: grab;
      .item_block_left_gallery_item{
        position: relative;
        height:100%;
        width:auto;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

JQUERY

```
    $(".item_block_left_gallery").draggable({
      scroll: false,
      axis: "x",
  });
```

The intended result is only being able to scroll/drag horizontally as far as the images go, with no white space on the left or right sides.

Comment: Similar to object collision detection, you need to detect when the items left position has reached a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4ak6q0zu/44/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var bounds = {
    left: $(".item_block_left_gallery").position().left
  };
  bounds.right = bounds.left - $(".item_block_left_gallery").width() - $(".item_block_left").width() + 10;

  $(".item_block_left_gallery").draggable({
    scroll: false,
    axis: "x",
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var l = ui.position.left;
      if (l > bounds.left) {
        console.log("Hit Left Boundry");
        ui.position.left = bounds.left;
      }
      if (l <= bounds.right) {
        console.log("Hit Right Boundry");
        ui.position.left = bounds.right;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Using `drag` callback, you can check and set the `position` of the draggable item. Basing things off the left edge of the drag item, we can check and restrict the movement based on some specific boundaries. It appears that there was a 10px padding or margin on the right hand side, might just be white space, so I just adjusted to correct for this.

See more: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Hope that helps.